# Constructor called with generic type always picks parent type while more specific constructor exists

Tags: c#, generics

In the below code, I have re-produced a C# behavior that I ran into and can't understand.

The idea is:
A generic class with a type constraint (`Parent` here) has a method that returns `T` which can be, depending on implementation, either `Parent` or `child` (which derives from `Parent`).
The object returned is then passed to the constructor of a class which has two constructors, one accepting a `Parent` and the other a `Child`

The behavior I expected would be that both constructors would be called depending on the type of the passed object but only the constructor accepting a `Parent` is called.

Why is that so ? Do I have any way to obtain the behavior I expected ?

```
internal class Program
{
    internal static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new ParentLogicCode().DoAnInstanciation();
        new ChildLogicCode().DoAnInstanciation();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

internal class InstanciatedFromGenericClass
{
    internal InstanciatedFromGenericClass(Child thinggy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor with Child type called");
    }

    internal InstanciatedFromGenericClass(Parent thinggy)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor with Parent type called while acutal type is: " + thinggy.GetType());
    }
}

internal abstract class LogicCode<T> where T : Parent
{
    public void DoAnInstanciation()
    {
        var thinggy = GetThinggy();
        Console.WriteLine("Instanciating with type: " + thinggy.GetType());
        var instance = new InstanciatedFromGenericClass(thinggy);
    }

    protected abstract T GetThinggy();
}

internal class ParentLogicCode : LogicCode<Parent>
{
    protected override Parent GetThinggy() => new Parent();
}

internal class ChildLogicCode : LogicCode<Child>
{
    protected override Child GetThinggy() => new Child();
}

internal class Parent{}
internal class Child : Parent{}
```

The above program gives the following output:

```
Instanciating with type: GenericPolymorphismTest.Parent
Constructor with Parent type called while acutal type is: GenericPolymorphismTest.Parent
Instanciating with type: GenericPolymorphismTest.Child
Constructor with Parent type called while acutal type is: GenericPolymorphismTest.Child
```

We have currently fixed the problem by using the following code, but we would much prefer to avoid having to do that which kind of defeats the purpose of generics ...

```
if (toCast.GetType() == typeof(Parent))
{
    return new InstanciatedFromGenericClass((Parent)toCast);
}
if (toCast.GetType() == typeof(Child))
{
    return new InstanciatedFromGenericClass((Child)toCast);
}
```

Comment: The overload of `InstanciatedFromGenericClass()` is resolved at compile time. The only overload that makes any sense is the one that takes `Parent`, because all the compiler knows is that `T` is some subclass of `Parent`.

Comment: You should not have a generic class where you expect it to be one of two specific types.  If you want to support a type dealing with one of two different types have two classes, and use the class appropriate for the type you want to pass in.

Comment: Don't try to abuse generics for a problem that some other approach is well suited to solving. The way to choose a method dependent on `thinggy`'s actual runtime type is to call a virtual method on `thinggy`. If you want runtime overload resolution, you could declare `thinggy` `dynamic`, but IMO that's not a good substitute for learning how to use conventional language features to do what you need to.